# how to configure website menu in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm making a website on jekyll and I use this code for the menu:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
<li><a href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

But it adds to my menu an empty item of home page, that I don't need:

```
<li><a href="/"></a></li>
```

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original jekyll does :

```
{% for my_page in site.pages %}
  {% if my_page.title %}
  <a class="page-link" href="{{ my_page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ my_page.title }}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But your can test on any page variable.

If you want to discriminate page depending on a type, you can set a front matter variable like `type: toto` and then generate your menu like this :

```
{% for my_page in site.pages %}
  {% if my_page.type == 'toto' %}
  <a class="page-link" href="{{ my_page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ my_page.title }}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```